# What are the alternatives for testing commonjs modules?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, commonjs

Which javascript testing frameworks out there provide support for testing commonjs modules?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using expresso by Visionmedia in node.js

https://github.com/visionmedia/expresso

It extends the basic assert functions http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/assert.html

So the default style assert:

```
exports['test String#length'] = function() {
    assert.equal(6, 'foobar'.length);
};
```

can be made DRYer

```
exports['test String#length'] = function(){
    assert.length(6, 'foobar');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they have their own UnitTesting framework

http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Unit_Testing/1.0

http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Unit_Testing/1.1

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience, [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) is very good

Answer (score 0):

Should extends the standard asserts with some BDD style ones:

https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js